# Database is being used by another process ... but what process?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have written a very small C# program, that uses a very small SQL Server database, purely for some learning & testing purposes. The database is used in this one new project and nowhere else. However, I am getting problems whilst running Debugs where the program will not run, because the database "is being used by another process".

If I reboot my machine, it will work again, and then after a few test runs I will get the same problem again.

I have found many, many similar problems reported all over the Internet, but can find no definitive answer as to how to resolve this problem. Firstly, how do I find out what "other process" is using my .mdf & .ldf files ? Then, how do I get these files released & not held in order to stop this happening time after time after time ?!?

I am new to VS2010, SQL Server & C#, so please be quite descriptive in any replies you give me !!!

This is my code, as you can see, you couldn't get anything much more basic, I certainly shouldn't be running into so many problems !!!

```
namespace MySqlTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection myDB = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MEDESKTOP;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SqlTestDB.mdf;Initial Catalog=MySqlDB;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter myDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand mySqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

        string mySQLcmd;
        int myCount;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("myDB state = " + myDB.State.ToString());
            //Open SQL File
            myDB.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("myDB state = " + myDB.State.ToString());
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myCount++;
            MessageBox.Show("myCount = " + myCount.ToString());
            //Insert Record Into  SQL File
            mySqlCmd.Connection = myDB;
            mySqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Parent(ParentName) Values(myCount)";
            myDA = new SqlDataAdapter(mySqlCmd);
            mySqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Read Record From SQL File
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Read All Records From SQL File
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Delete Record From DQL File
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("myDB state = " + myDB.State.ToString());
            //Close SQL File
            myDB.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("myDB state = " + myDB.State.ToString());
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Quit
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get same error message when you run your application first time? If you get this error second time onwards, I guess your application didn't close db connection properly.

Comment: When I first run the program, it works fine, and continues to work, but I am debugging and stopping the program without logically completing it sometimes. There doesn't appear to be a regular point at which this starts occurring though, but maybe it is connected to my stopping the debug without closing the DB. Would VS2010 not handle that though ?!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely options:

1. A previous (crashed) instance of your program
2. Visual Studio (with a Table designer open or something similar)

You can check 1) with TaskManager and 2) by looking in Server Explorer. Your db should show a small red cross meaning 'closed'.

And you should rewrite your code to close connections ASAP. Use try/finally or `using(){ }` blocks.

Comment: Well, with regard to rewriting my code, that is the reason for this small program, so that I can ascertain the best way for me to code my SQL-Server processing for use in my real program !! In Seerver Explorer my DB has the red cross, but I am still getting the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

This is the rewritten code, using the "*Using*" statements. When I execute the program and click on Insert Record Into SQL File, off it goes, completes the process with myCount = 1 (though I'm not 100% sure that it is actually doing a physical Write, am I missing a command that actually "commits" the update ?!?) and re-displays the Form.

If I then click on Insert Record Into SQL File again, I get an error as follows :

> SqlException was unhandled
>
> Cannot open user default database. Login failed. Login failed for user
>   'MEDESKTOP\Gary'.

This is the program (I am the only user on this PC and have full Admin rights, the "State" of the database at this point is, according to Properties, Closed, so it looks like the first pass through the code did as was expected ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MySqlTest
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int myCount;
    string myDBlocation = @"Data Source=MEDESKTOP;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\mySQLtest.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=False";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myCount++;
        MessageBox.Show("myCount = " + myCount.ToString());
        //Insert Record Into  SQL File
        myDB_Insert();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Read Record From SQL File

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Read All Records From SQL File

    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Delete Record From SQL File
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Quit
        myDB_Close();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Close(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void myDB_Insert()
    {
        using (SqlConnection myDB = new SqlConnection(myDBlocation))
        using (SqlCommand mySqlCmd = myDB.CreateCommand())
        {
            myDB.Open(); **<<< Program fails here, 2nd time through**
            mySqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Parent (ParentName) VALUES(@ParentNameValue)";
            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentNameValue", myCount);
            mySqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myDB.Close();
        }
        return;
    }

    void myDB_Close()
    {
        using (SqlConnection myDB = new SqlConnection(myDBlocation))
        using (SqlCommand mySqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            myDB.Close();
        }
        return;
    }

}
}
```

I don't understand why I am suddenly losing access to my own file that I am already using ?!?

Answer (score 0):

try running sp_who2 to see the list of process.

FYI: you don't need to reboot your machine, worst case, restart SQL Server service

Comment: I will try this in a little while, have to collect the kids from school right now ... if you are correct that will save me a LOT of time !!!

Comment: OK, VS2010 wouldn't let me open a new query, it said "Unable to open the physical file ..... Operating system error 32: "32(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason:15105). An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file ..... failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.", so I ran sp_who2 in SQL Server Management Studio and got 31 results, only the bottom 2 of which seem relevant to this database, i.e. they have MySqlDB in the DBName column.

Comment: Both lines say that the Program Name is "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query, then the first line says Status = RUNNABLE, Command = SELECT INTO, CPU Time = 125 & DiskIO = 20, whilst the second line says Status = Sleeping, Command = AWAITING COMMAND, CPU Time = 0 & DiskIO = 0 ... so there is no mention of Visual Studio using the file(s) !!!

Comment: If I try to take the DB offline, I get an error as follows "Set offline failed for Database 'MySqlDB'. An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database 'MySqlDB'. Try again later. ALTER DATABASE statement failed. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5061)" ... but, if I run the sp-who2 again, the "Status = Sleeping, Command = AWAITING COMMAND" query line is gone, but the "Status = RUNNABLE, Command = SELECT INTO" line is still there (I have no idea if any of this is relevant !)

Comment: ok one thing at a time. When I said to restart SQL server as an option to reboot your PC I meant run services.msc, look for the sql server service and then restart it. try that

Comment: I restarted MSSQLSERVER, then SQLEXPRESS, then restarted both of them, but I still have the same problem. I'm just trying Process Explorer as suggested by GrantJ (below)

Comment: I had to go into Services & find MSSQLSERVER, change the Start option to Manual, then physically Stop it ... than and only then, was I able to delete the files in the bin\debug folder !!! I altered the Start option back to Automatic & started the Service, and at last, it is all working again !!! Now I have to find out why it is happening and to prevent it from happening again ...

Comment: but that's what I said you to do :) ok, glad it solved one of the problems. Now, you sure you are always clicking the button6 to close the connection? Why dont you add the code myDB.Close(); to the form_close event so you are sure the connection is being closed when the form is closed

Comment: Thanks Diego, sorry I took a while to reply, didn't get to do any work yesterday, too many kids, too much noise !!! As I've said, I'm new to C# & SQL Server, and this little program will, I hope, let me see the best (and clearest) ways to integrate the SQL code into my real program. Yes, the Form_Close event code seems a good idea, I'll do that. Do you know whether the "Using" command is a good idea in this sort of case ? I am researching it, as I've read that it prevents files being locked & resources being hogged, but obviously it's always helpful to get advice from people more experienced.

Comment: yes "using" is very good, but you'll need to rethink your logic. The using(connection) { <block_of_code> } will close the connection when <block_of_code> ends, so you wont need to close on the button or on the form close. This is a very good approach indeed

Comment: Hi @Diego, I've rewritten things and I thought I was happy with my code, but I am getting another strange error, I've put the code into the Answer Your Question box ...

Comment: It's "Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'MEDESKTOP\Gary'." ... I've just uploaded it as an Answer ...

Answer (score 0):

IIRC using `AttachDbFilename` spins up a `SqlServr.exe` process running under the user account your process is using, separate from the SqlServer instance running as a service (so stopping the MsSqlServer service doesn't stop this issue). In the case of a dirty exit, sometimes this process does not get cleaned up. I suspect that killing this process will free up the db files.

Comment: I had to go into Services & find MSSQLSERVER, change the Start option to Manual, then physically Stop it ... than and only then, was I able to delete the files in the bin\debug folder !!! I altered the Start option back to Automatic & started the Service, and at last, it is all working again !!! Now I have to find out why it is happening and to prevent it from happening again ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) written by Mark Russinovich, a Technical Fellow at Microsoft. It's a standard swiss-army tool in the pocket of Windows Admins/Developers. It can show you what processes are holding handles on resources in the system.

Once you've got Process Explorer installed, try the following:

1. Get your system into a fail-state (such that running your program doesn't work).
2. Start up Process Explorer (you'll need to be an Admin to make full-use of its features).
3. Click "Find" in the menu bar at the top and type in the name of your .mdf or .ldf files.

The search results should display a process/service with a handle on one of the resources still held by a wrongly-terminated process.

Comment: It finds the LDF file, but as per my reply to Diego (above) killing the process is not releasing it :-( !!!

Comment: I had to go into Services & find MSSQLSERVER, change the Start option to Manual, then physically Stop it ... than and only then, was I able to delete the files in the bin\debug folder !!! I altered the Start option back to Automatic & started the Service, and at last, it is all working again !!! Now I have to find out why it is happening and to prevent it from happening again ...

Answer (score 0):

Working with VS 2010 and Entity Frameworks using SQL Server I've run into this more than a few times. In my case it happened when I tried to run the program and I had a query open in the Server Explorer. Once it fails I had to drop all the connections to get it to work again.

VS2010 copies the source database (an `.MDF` and `.LDF` file) that you work with in Server Explorer to the projects debug folder. This is the copy you are working with at runtime. When this file is copied is controled by the MDF property `Copy to Output Directory` by default it is set to `Copy always`. This means it will try and copy the file on a new build or run and if you have it open elsewhere it fails and then it gets hung up.

The way to see the connection is to open the SQL Server Management Console. By default VS2010 is using a user instance of SQL Server as specified in the connection string. In the case of Entity Frameworks it is in the App.Config XML.

The user instance is a separate in memory copy of SQL Server that has all the user rights assigned to the logged in user. To get to it you need to find the proper connection.

Running this query from the main instance of SQL will show all of the User Instance connections.

```
SELECT owning_principal_name, instance_pipe_name, heart_beat FROM sys.dm_os_child_instances
```

This will return something that looks like this:

```
   |owning_principle_name | instance_pipe_name                      | heart_beat
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | MyServer\Admin       | \\.\pipe\91B3063E-CD0F-4B\tsql\query\   | dead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  | MyServer\Rich        | \\.\pipe\B04A1D3B-6268-49\tsql\query\   | alive
```

If you copy the instance name and use it as the server name in a new connection, running as the user associated with it you will see your data from the debug folder.

Now if you right click on the database and select `Tasks >` `Detach...` You will open a `Detach Database` dialog check the `Drop Connections` checkbox next to the database file name and click `OK`.

The database will be removed from the list and you should be able to build and run you application.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution at: http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920022220

Right-click the database in VS's database explorer and click close connection between debugging sessions and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing is go Server Explorer.  Choose the problem database. Right-click and choose "Close Connection".

If it is already closed, connect and disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is already SqlTestDB.mdf is attached.
I have faced this problem before, simply go to Ms Sql server and detach the database then rebuild your connection at Server Explorer in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the dbase at the start and no certainty that it is being released when finished. Really you are waiting for the memory manager to sort it out, it depends then on how busy the system is as to when the file can be released.

I think that you need to change this to "Open when needed".

I for example put the code to access any database in it's own class, once the actions have been completed I release it.

Opening and closing does have overhead, but I have found I can live with it by doing the following,

Have more than one entry point in your class, one for single transactions, and another for multiple transactions. For example

```
 S_UpdateSingleRecord(...)
 M_UpdateManyRecords(...)
```

I find that in most applications these can be static, because they in themselves do not store data they only pass it through to and from the database. It only loses it's static status if I want to cache something for my application.

I use 'using' in the S_SingleTransaction() because it cleans it for me. But I leave the Multiple entrypoint open and close it when my calling function finishes. I have never had this lock problem with a single mdf and one application. It would come back into play with one mdf and multiple applications, in these cases you need to make use of the MSSQL as a service dbase instead, you would find it just as easy to setup in your Visual Studio, and then in other applications you already have that database on the list in your toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Task Manager` (pressing Ctrl + Shift + Esc), go to tab `Services`, sort by `Name` and look for `MSSSQLSERVER`. Right click on it and select `Stop`, remove the file (.mdf or .ldf that is causing the issue). Rigth click again over `MSSSQLSERVER` and select 'Restart`.