# Unable to open physical file Operating system error 32 "32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)"

Tags: vb.net

I was trying to attach a database file, located in the data directory, on connect to a local SQL Server Express instance.
I received a message: **Unable to open the physical file "D:\Project1\bin\Debug\Database\db_project_log.ldf". Operating system error 32: "32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)".**

Look at my code below:

```
Sub GetData()

    Dim cnGS As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rsSelect As ADODB.Recordset

    cnGS = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    rsSelect = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    With cnGS
        .Provider = "SQLNCLI"
        .Mode = ConnectModeEnum.adModeReadWrite
        .ConnectionString = "SERVER=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=" _
                            & Application.StartupPath & "/Database/db_project.mdf;" & _
                            "Database=db_project; Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
        .Open()
    End With

    Dim sSQLSelect = "SELECT * FROM v_billing WHERE bill_id = 123"

    rsSelect.Open(sSQLSelect, cnGS, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic, LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly)
    rsSelect.MoveFirst()
End Sub
```

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: Just a guess, but always close the connection. Don't leave that cnGS open specially with AttachDbFileName. Also looks at this for hints http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195443/database-is-being-used-by-another-process-but-what-process

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.sqlserver.server/S2JwwVZbMdo

Comment: @Steve, i was trying to close the connection already but it doesn't help. and I think It generated the error before I open connection.
**Unable to open the physical file "D:\Project1\bin\Debug\Database\db_project_log.ldf". Operating system error 32: "32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)".**

Comment: Please search this site for the specific error message. The question has been asked (and answered) dozens of times before. (Start with the Related list to the right of this question, for instance.)