# Git error when trying to commit from Visual Studio 2015 ( file opensdf)

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, tfs

I am getting an error when I am trying to do a commit from Visual Studio 2015:

An error occurred. Detailed message: Could not open 'C:/ABC/DEFG-windows-universal/AAAA.Win10.opensdf': The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I have tryied to reboot, and to delete the file but I have the same issue.  Do I need to use the command line to commit my changes? (I am pushing to Master and I am the only one working on this app)

Comment: Seems like that kind of files (...sdf extension) are database files. So, maybe is used by another process related to databases; Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195443/database-is-being-used-by-another-process-but-what-process

Can you try closing VisualStudio and use git on console to create your commit? (If you really need/want to push that file)

Comment: I have no idea what is this file is for, I did not create this database file ( and i am the only one working and developing this application )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you need to add that file to your `.gitignore`.

Simply create a `.gitignore` that contains the following :

```
*.opensdf
```

Easier, though, is to let Visual Studio create the default `.gitignore` in your repository, or download the [default Visual Studio .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) and add it to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the locked file to gitignore isn't an option for me because I want it versioned but I may not need to commit it frequently with other minor changes I'm making. Even if I temporarily exclude locked files it still won't let me commit unlocked ones. This is indeed very annoying.

What I find works for me is use of another Git client to commit files outside of VS2015. Also not a perfect solution but it does the job. The only other solution I found is closing VS, opening it again and committing files before doing anything else.

Comment: Please don't commit you `opensdf` file.   It's per-user data that isn't meant to be shared.

Comment: My file was an mdf. Still, not the best strategy to version control a whole database so I removed it.

Comment: Ah - that is different then.  That's still part of your project (not internal data like the opensdf file) and so a legitimate decision to add it to VC.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with .opendb files. Added *.opendb to my ignore list worked wonders. Thanks for the help.