# An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Os (Error).Failed to open .opensdf

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, github, libgit2

I am using github whith visual studio and I keep getting this eror:

> An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2.
>   Category = Os (Error). Failed to open 'C:/Users/Roy
>   Malka/Desktop/github/projexm/projexmp/projexmp.opensdf'

I tried everything. Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git error when trying to commit from Visual Studio 2015 ( file opensdf)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811559/git-error-when-trying-to-commit-from-visual-studio-2015-file-opensdf)

Answer (score 1):

When do you get this error?

You probably need to add the opensdf files to your .gitignore file. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811559/git-error-when-trying-to-commit-from-visual-studio-2015-file-opensdf/33812412#33812412) provides good options for accomplishing this.